# How to transform a Map<String, List<String>> into a List<Map<String, String>> and get Cartesian product?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream, cartesian-product

Using Java I am attempting to create the Cartesian Product of a map which contains `String` keys and `List<String>` values. I need to preserve the values of the keys when creating the list like so:

- From a `Map<String, List<String>>` Object
- To a `List<Map<String, String>>` Object

I also have the requirement that when a `List<String>` value in the original map is empty it should still be treated as a single value when creating the Cartesian Product so as to avoid multiplying by 0 and creating no maps. For example the following map:

```
{
    "Location Number" = {"100", "500"}
    "Department Number" = {"11", "22", "33"}
    "District Number" = {}
    "Preferred Language" = {"en-US"}
}
```

Is translated to:

```
{
    {
        "Location Number" = "100"
        "Department Number" = "11"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    },
    {
        "Location Number" = "100"
        "Department Number" = "22"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    },
    {
        "Location Number" = "100"
        "Department Number" = "33"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    },
    {
        "Location Number" = "500"
        "Department Number" = "11"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    },
    {
        "Location Number" = "500"
        "Department Number" = "22"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    },
    {
        "Location Number" = "500"
        "Department Number" = "33"
        "District Number" = {}
        "Preferred Language" = "en-US"
    }
}
```

Below is the code I am currently using to accomplish a similar translation, but it does not retain the key, which I need. I do not know if this is possible to accomplish using Java 8 Streams in general.

```java
private static List<List<String>> createRuleListFromMap(Map<String, List<String>> ruleMap) {
    List<List<String>> ruleList = new ArrayList<>();
    cartesianProduct(ruleMap.values()).forEach(ruleList::add);
    return ruleList;
}

private static <T> Stream<List<T>> cartesianProduct(Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collections) {
    return cartesianProduct(new ArrayList<Collection<T>>(collections), Collections.emptyList());
}

private static <T> Stream<List<T>> cartesianProduct(List<? extends Collection<T>> collections, List<T> current) {
    return collections.isEmpty() ? Stream.of(current) : collections.get(0).stream().flatMap(e -> {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(current);
        list.add(e);
        return cartesianProduct(collections.subList(1, collections.size()), list);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple example how to transform `Map<String,List<String>>` to `List<Map<String,String>>`:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class StreamTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        var map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        map.put("key1", Arrays.asList("value1", "value2", "value3"));
        map.put("key2", Arrays.asList("value4", "value5", "value6"));

        var list = map.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(v -> Map.of(e.getKey(), v)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        log.info(list.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This provides a single map per entry (key mapped to elements in entry list), not a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

You can first represent the elements of lists, each as `Map<String,String>`, and get *a stream of lists of maps*, and then `reduce` this stream to a single *list* by sequentially summing pairs of inner maps to get the *Cartesian product*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNbxoxEL3zK6acvBVsAlEvSYtUtZUqlaSVaHupejDLAAavvbJng1CU307GZkEElg9VHQl21543b/w8MzP5KNuz0Xy1UnlhHcGMF9KSlE7f3jUO1jw5lHnYahTlUKsMMi29h3upDDw1gK1a9ySJH49WjSDnXTEgp8zkz1@QbuKTyjnYvSzerzdb0Feeqo9ej3EFfACDC143cxx9lX4avHsiudvC2SktShLNvs2Y0hp4KPMhuuY6WmrHotm5vubP5jt@JHXQz1hIRzkaqgN3ArbbDf83N0cCsLNTWR08AODqCh6@/wRpAPOClqB5981hmB8Ox@gcjqAvzaSUE9yNhKb9axD5t8io166AW@0CA4sXQvOx3HKAJJLq/kSyDbCxlB1FdIR2D@JLOkH6LXWJp3Ab4wNGRtQYZPQg/e7FVmkdhUd6JgnkDAvH3ebwDZciaXFBueQk/74WGymOk2ZWa8xIfFo/rfMp2RBGJDVUTKEMoctxpCQh2JL40g6VLBDnYrD0hHnKPre3BedB2tRGXAsLdhzl80AWJHjOW2NcOQzP1VFmKETY7bSiUzcJusWFi24qs/lQmdgsPlArY9CFUvHHtRprSSyuYK/Ohq17nm2HdWZ5RoRbVRhZaWFPc74qDv51A@/TWff9mVLVAeQ8TC4Cb@zM4DlleWzoj1pHvf4F1L0Q5JBKZxh73v05Od@/fC@71fEfe2edqD/WpnUQS1N0C@Xx9eA87AnrvmiPm1xC4ml0r/LZGZgcdcyH0/vdG@KmY44js2lt867lfW48r1Yv)

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("Location Number", List.of("100", "500"));
map.put("Department Number", List.of("11", "22", "33"));
map.put("District Number", List.of("")); // NOT an empty list!
map.put("Preferred Language", List.of("en-US"));
```

```java
List<Map<String, String>> list = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                // list elements as Map<String,String>
                .map(str -> Map.of(entry.getKey(), str))
                // List<Map<String,String>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // stream of lists to a single list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // combinations of inner maps
                .flatMap(map1 -> list2.stream()
                        // join entries of two maps
                        .map(map2 -> {
                            Map<String, String> mp =
                                    new LinkedHashMap<>();
                            mp.putAll(map1);
                            mp.putAll(map2);
                            return mp;
                        }))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // returns List<Map<String,String>
        // otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

```java
// final output
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Intermediate output:

```
[{Location Number=100}, {Location Number=500}]
[{Department Number=11}, {Department Number=22}, {Department Number=33}]
[{District Number=}]
[{Preferred Language=en-US}]
```

Final output:

```
{Location Number=100, Department Number=11, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
{Location Number=100, Department Number=22, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
{Location Number=100, Department Number=33, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
{Location Number=500, Department Number=11, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
{Location Number=500, Department Number=22, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
{Location Number=500, Department Number=33, District Number=, Preferred Language=en-US}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Convert a map of lists into a list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66700962/15675591)</sup>